# Can read happen in true parallelism?

Tags: multithreading

If there are multiple threads running on separate cores (true parallelism) and they access the same variable all in the same time. If they are guaranteed to just read the variable, can the read happen in true parallelism?

Consider the following example:

If we define the access function to that variable (called `bool stop`) as:

```
bool const & readOnlyAccesToVariable()  // Returns a unchangeble reference to the variable
```

The variable is private to a *master* thread. The duty of a master thread is to stop the execution of a large number of *worker* threads on separate cores as simultaneously as possible. The *workers* are stopped if the `stop` changes to `1`.

The worker periodically does:

```
if (readOnlyAccesToVariable() ) break;
```

Will some of the workers bi stopped simultaneously (meaning that the read of stop is not serialized but parallel)?

Comment: Define `true parallelism`. In hardware, I can imagine only one 'circuit' at any given time is allowed to communicate with memory. So if the variable was not hard copied in memory, accessing the same value on different processors would be sequential from the very beginning (hardware limited). But maybe I am wrong and this is where Direct Memory Access comes into play, though that is more to read or write memory while the CPU can continue doing other stuff.

Comment: @MikedeKlerk Added an example to clarify the question

Comment: @MikedeKlerk DMA is for peripherals like hard drives or FireWire devices to write directly to RAM and not bother the CPU at all. There are different ways to solve the memory access problem, and I don't think they all serialize the traffic. Some use coherency traffic to notify other cores to invalidate their caches, for example. If this is crucial (and I don't think it is) then it'll depend on Alan's actual hardware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as no thread will modify the value, reads are perfectly ok.

An immutable variable by definition cannot be written, so yes that makes it thread safe in that respect.

However you of course have to make sure it gets initialized in a thread-safe way, and that no threads will start reading until it has been initialized.

Comment: I've updated the question based on a comment to make the question clearer.

Comment: @Alan What you wrote is actually the recommended course of action for how to stop worker threads.

Comment: In the worst case a thread will read `false` and keep working, and immediately after the master sets the value to `true`. That worker won't know until it checks again. It has to explicitly check (like with your `if`).

Comment: But is the simultaneous read truly simultaneous or are the worker threads reading the variable one by one. This would be important if there are some real time constraints for stopping a large number of threads.

Comment: They're all *allowed* to do it at the same time. If they're actually all running in parallel and the workflow makes them all hit that read at the exact same time, and the memory controllers somehow return the value at the same time, and it makes it through the caches at the same time, then yes they can all read it at the same time.

Comment: However "large number of threads" is likely larger than the number of cores, so there will be some lag while threads wait the turn on the CPU. But again, the longest time a thread can possibly lag is the amount of time between polls.

Comment: Reads are a multithreaded programmer's wet dream. It's the writes that cause headaches.

Comment: So it depends on the memory controllers. With sufficient cores (every thread on separate core/processor) we can have a parallel worker execution, however the amount of parallelism (in this specific case) depends on the implemented by of the memory controller.

Comment: No, that depends entirely on how tightly coupled your problem is. If that flag is the only communication the threads have then you're golden up to thousands of cores. You're really making mountains out of mole hills here. You've got the right approach, if it's causing you problems then you should be more specific about how.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand your problem.

You want to terminate a lot of worker threads by setting a stop variable to true. This is fine, but please don't forget to make stop volatile so the compiler knows that the value of stop can change anytime and it must reread stop every time it has to access it (and not use value it might have just written to a register).

You also say that you need to terminate all threads as parallel as possible. First of all I do not understand why you need to do so. Second I don't understand why you are doing a polling mechanism when you need all threads to terminate exactly the same time. Why don't you use an event, set that and let the operating system wake up all threads waiting on the event? If you can't do so because your threads are not just waiting for the stop event but also doing things, then again I do not understand your requirements. If the threads are doing things and from time to time check the stop variable, then how do you want to achieve absolut parallel termination? This seems quite contradictory.

Comment: I see your point. The example with large number of thread is fictional, and it was the situation that came to mind in which real parallel access would occur. If there is a large enough number of threads running on separate cores and each of them checks the stop variable often enough (in which case the maximum latency for stopping a worker thread is the time between two checks of the stop variable)  some of them will try to read at the same time. I wondered if the reading would happen in parallel or it could pose a latency larger then one mentioned above in this comment.